# intellij idea 2016.2 community edition PHP Support?

Tags: php, intellij-idea

I've just installed intellij idea 2016.2 community edition and when looking in the plugin repo in settings it seems to have every Language you have ever heard of (and a lot you haven't) apart from PHP, which is surprising.

I did a search and found https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6610?pr=idea which says its **Compatible with IntelliJ IDEA** but when I try and install the plugin it says

> Plugin 'PHP' is incompatible with this installation

Doe's anyone else have this problem?

Comment: @simon thanks for the sarcastic reply, very helpful

Comment: Well it did help you, didn't it? Seriously, this question could have been avoided easily by just putting a minimum on effort into research.

Comment: sorry @simon that we are all not as great as you, sorry to have ruined your day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not supported and is a poor error message. Jetbrains wants you to purchase IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate or PhpStorm, which is how they make money.

Comment: Yep its all about profit, they deliberately ensure PHP wont be supported